# Does "show" take a gerund or an infinitive?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, grammaticality-in-context, infinitive-vs-gerund

Please help me choose the correct one.

The novelist **shows** his two characters (enter/entering) a truce.

Comment: I think the gerund phrases can be used to modify the object. However, "enter" is considered as the bare infinitive not infinitive.

Comment: *The novelist shows his two characters **entering** a truce = who enter.* It's a short relative clause.

Comment: What I want to say "shows them as they engage in the act of entering a truce"?

Comment: I don't mean to imply a relative clause

Comment: The novelist shows how his two characters enter a truce

Comment: You said it yourself, @asef:  ... *as they enter* a truce.  Or is this a test question where you must choose between *enter* and *entering*?

Comment: @TRomano I have seen structures like"*I watched him climb/climbing the wall*" that can imply slightly differents meaning depending on usage of gerund or bare infinitive. I think, the "bare infinitive" implies a completed action, however, the gerund implies a progressive action. Am I right? By the way, does show accept bare infinitives?

Comment: With **I watched him climb the tree** there is no guarantee that it means "I saw him get to the top of the tree". If getting to the top were important needed information, the listener would probably follow up with a question "Did he reach the top?" Do you mean "show {direct object} {bare infinitive}"?

Comment: Possible and clearer: shows them at the moment of entering a truce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Show** takes a gerund in your example.

I believe these are the 2 most common correct constructions involving **show**:

- show + object + gerund, meaning "depict the object as it engages in an action"
- show + object, meaning "depict/demonstrate/reveal the object"

Answer (score 0):

The verb *show* in the context offered presupposes using the pattern **show something**. It means that the sentence needs the grammatical structure *Noun+show+that+noun+enter+truce*. Transformation of the grammar construction gives *The novelist shows that his two characters enter a truce*.
We may construct other syntax, though the focus of the sentence will be changed from the context offered, *The novelist shows his two characters entering a truce*. The focus of the sentence is not the fact describing the action of the two characters, but a description itself of the action in which the two characters happened to be engaged in.
With this mentioned above, the answer to the question in the OP is that, we should use participle *entering* in the case.